# Loading imageUrl from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase-storage

Im trying to load imageUrl from Firebase Storage.My issue is that once a user creates a profile picture it is not being loaded into the ImageView. The image is being saved in the storage and the Url is also being saved to my database but it is not being loaded, the imageview is just empty. I added some comments to the code to help explain its function. Any recommendations?

```
    mBio = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Bio);
    mNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    mPhoneField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    mProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
    mBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    mConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    usersDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userId);

    getUserInfo();
    mProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
   // Confirm Button OnClick
    mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveUserInformation();
        }
    });

// Get saved user information and Profile Picture if exist
private void getUserInfo() {
    usersDb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                if(map.get("name")!=null){
                    name = map.get("name").toString();
                    mNameField.setText(name);
                }
                if(map.get("Bio")!=null) {
                    bio = map.get("Bio").toString();
                    mBio.setText(bio);
                }
                if(map.get("phone")!=null){
                    phone = map.get("phone").toString();
                    mPhoneField.setText(phone);
                }
                Glide.with(mProfileImage).clear(mProfileImage);
                    if(map.get("profileImageUrl")!=null){
                    profileImageUrl = map.get("profileImageUrl").toString();

                    switch(profileImageUrl){
                        case "default":
                            Glide.with(getApplication()).load(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(mProfileImage);
                            break;
                        default:
                            Glide.with(getApplication()).load(profileImageUrl).into(mProfileImage);
                            break;
                    } } } }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }}); }

 // Save User's information and set Profile Picture
private void saveUserInformation() {
    name = mNameField.getText().toString();
    phone = mPhoneField.getText().toString();
    bio = mBio.getText().toString();

    Map users = new HashMap();
    users.put("name", name);
    users.put("phone", phone);
    users.put("Bio",bio);
    usersDb.updateChildren(users);

   // Add image to Firebase Storage
    if(resultUri != null){
        StorageReference filepath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profileImages").child(userId);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplication().getContentResolver(), resultUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putBytes(data);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Task<Uri> downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                Map users = new HashMap();
                users.put("profileImageUrl", downloadUrl.toString());
                usersDb.updateChildren(users);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        });
    }else{
        finish();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        resultUri = data.getData();
        mProfileImage.setImageURI(resultUri);
    }
}
```

Here is the solution to the problem.

```
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {

                        Uri downloadUrl = task.getResult();
                        Map users = new HashMap();
                        users.put("profileImageUrl", downloadUrl.toString());
                        usersDb.updateChildren(users);
                        finish();
                        return;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You're making a very common mistake - you don't actually have a URL yet. You need to use that Task correctly.

Comment: @DougStevenson So the issue is in my OnSuccess Listener. Can you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: I figured out what you were saying. Posted the solution.